# Orthogonal basis of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Let us define the basis of polynomials given by:
$$
\begin{array}\
P_0=1, \\
P_1=x, \\
P_2=x(x-1), \\
P_3=x(x-1)(x-2), \\
P_4=x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3), \ldots\\
\end{array}
$$
I would like to know if this basis is orthogonal with respect to some measure. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, you could define an ad hoc inner product by saying that if $p(x) = \sum a_ip_i$ and $q(x)=\sum b_ip_i$, then $\langle p,q\rangle = \sum a_ib_i$, which would make it an orthogonal (even orthonormal) basis. But presumably you are looking for more than just "some" measure?

Comment: Ps: I was thinking about an inner product of the form $\int dx P_i(x) P_j(x) \mu(x)$ for some measure $\mu(x)$

Comment: You should explain more clearly what kind of measure you are asking? A real measure on the real line? A complex measure on a subset of the complex plane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a sequence of monic polynomials is orthogonal with respect a measure, it satisfies a three-term recurrence 
\[
  p_{n+1}(t) = (t-a_n)p_n(t) - b_n p_{n-1}(t)
\]
where $b_n>0$. From this it follows that consecutive terms in the sequence cannot have a common zero. Your sequence fails badly on this test.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed you are right. But can we define something similar to a orthogonality condition? e.g. we can also consider the family of polynomials P_n(x) = x^n, which is a complete basis, but in this case we can define, for instance $<P_n P_m> = \int \frac{dz}{z} P_n(x) P_{-m}(x)$, where the integral is a contour integral around zero.

Comment: Very nice answer! Do you know of a reference elaborating on this link between orthogonality and recurrences?

Comment: Any text book on orthogonal polynomials should treat this, it’s quite basic. My “Algebraic Combinatorics” discusses it at lengh too ( if you’ll forgive the plug).

Comment: The 3 term recurrence relation does not immediately imply that the $p_n$ do not have a common root. In fact, if $p_n$ and $p_{n-1}$ have the same root, the recursion implies that $p_{n+1}$ has also the same root. The reason that common roots are not allowed is more subtle. In any event, I do consider that Fernando’s question is a very interesting one, and deserves a more informative answer, if possible.